# Value Error: Format does not match while converting string to datime.date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am converting the following string `2020-02-14 20:56:00` to `datetime.date` format. But am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2020-02-14 20:56:00' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Here is the code I am using:

```py
from datetime import datetime 
date_and_time = '2020-02-14 20:56:00'
date_and_time = datetime.strptime(date_and_time, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Replace '/' with '-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `ValueError` specifies the use of incorrect format string.
 
To resolve this error you have to replace `/` with `-`.
 Here is correct code:**

```
from datetime import datetime 
date_and_time = '2020-02-14 20:56:00'
date_and_time = datetime.strptime(date_and_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Hope it helps you:)